# same NAS, same folder, but different groups showed in two different hosts, why?

Tags: group, shared-folders, nas, chgrp

I have a strange behaviour with a shared NAS between multiple hosts.

Every host reaches a shared folder mounted on `/sharedfolder` on the same source (##.###.###.###:/filesystem, where ## are the numbers of the original ip address).

On the **Host1** is shown the group `httpd` on the folder `/sharedfolder`, but on the Host2 is shown `mygroup` for the same resources.

How's possible and what should I do in order to obtain the same group information on each host?

**Host1:**

```
[myuser@host1 sharedfolder]$ df -h
File system                  Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root   97G  4,4G     93G   5% /
devtmpfs                     2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        2,0G   84M    1,9G   5% /run
tmpfs                        2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   1014M  130M    885M  13% /boot
##.###.###.###:/filesystem    61G  3,0G     58G   5% /sharedfolder
tmpfs                        395M     0    395M   0% /run/user/1001

[myuser@host1 ~]$ cd /sharedfolder/
[myuser@host1 sharedfolder]$ ll
totale 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 root    httpd 4096  4 dic 10.50 folder1
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser httpd 4096 29 apr 16.49 folder2
drwxrwxr-x 5 root    httpd 4096 13 feb 23.09 folder3
drwxrwxr-x 3 myuser httpd 4096 21 apr 15.12 folder4
```

**Host2:**

```
[myuser@host2 ~]$ df -h
File system                              Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root               97G   45G     53G  46% /
devtmpfs                                 7,9G     0    7,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                    7,9G     0    7,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                    7,9G   76M    7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                                    7,9G     0    7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                               1014M  130M    885M  13% /boot
##.###.###.###:/filesystem                61G  3,0G     58G   5% /sharedfolder
tmpfs                                    1,6G     0    1,6G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/vg_fs-lv_fs                  400G  295G    106G  74% /anothervolume
tmpfs                                    1,6G     0    1,6G   0% /run/user/1001
[myuser@host2 ~]$ cd /sharedfolder/
[myuser@host2 sharedfolder]$ ll
totale 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 root    mygroup 4096  4 dic 10.50 folder1
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser mygroup 4096 29 apr 16.49 folder2
drwxrwxr-x 5 root    mygroup 4096 13 feb 23.09 folder3
drwxrwxr-x 3 myuser mygroup 4096 21 apr 15.12 folder4
```

Comment: How do you mount the share on each host? user-id and group-id can be modified with the mount command.

Comment: @bey0nd I didn't mount the share. Do you mean that `chgrp` is not enough to make the assignment for all hosts?

Comment: How does '##.###.###.###:/filesystem' get mounted on host1 and host2? Can you also pls. add the output of `sudo mount | grep sharedfolder` to your question.

Comment: I think I have found one possible explanation: if the user or the group doesn't exist on the specific host, it shows numeric values for owner or group name, otherwise it mantains the right associations. In the specific case I think that the change could have been made on host2, so host1 still keep its own original association.

Comment: What do you get with `ls -n` within the shared folder?